LoadJob in BigQuery gives 400 Unsupported field type: JSON
I have a table in BigQuery with multiple columns, one of them being JSON. Say for example, col1 is STRING, col2 is INT and col3 is JSON. I have the data in a Polars Dataframe which I am trying to write into BigQuery. Inside the Dataframe, the col3 is stored as STRING.
The write attempt is done through in two steps:

Create a stream variable and use df.write_parquet(stream) to have a stream pointing to the data.
client.load_table_from_file(stream, destination, job_config) method from the bigquery python sdk. The LoadJobConfig parameter also specifies the schema of the destination table (which has the JSON type specified).

When executing this, the error: google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Unsupported field type: JSON; reason: invalid, message: Unsupported field type: JSON is thrown.
How to resolve this? If I change the data type to STRING everything works, but I'd really like to keep the data type as JSON as there are existing scripts reading from the table.

Ultimately, I resolved this by side stepping the problem: by using the legacy streaming API. I tried using the new streaming API as well but it was way too painful to meaningfully convert the types to and fro from protobuf. The legacy API was able to do what I wanted extremely easily.

Do you have example code for this?

Can't share the code, but it is just a single line. The bigquery client has a method which takes the pandas dataframe and writes it: https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquery/latest/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client#google_cloud_bigquery_client_Client_insert_rows_from_dataframe
